# Linking Rails 5 apps in subpaths using assets from other app

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

I have two different Rails 5 applications on the same server with Nginx and Passenger. One is served under a `/subpath` with an nginx `location {}` block with `scope 'subpath' do` in routes.rb and both `config.assets.prefix` and c`onfig.relative_url_root` set to `/subpath`.

I tried to serve the other application on a different subpath, but is has some Javascript and plugins that expect it to be on the domain route so it turned out to be more trouble than it was worth, so its on the domain route.

Mostly everything is working, but when the applications link to one another, there is some CSS and JS leakage from the other application. If I refresh the page, it fixes itself.

Using the inspector after linking from the app in `www.domain.com/subpath/foo` to `www.domain.com/bar`, I can see that `www.domain.com/bar` is using some code from `www.domain.com/subpath/application.css` (the compiled production version). It does the same in both directions.

I assumed this was some kind of caching issue, so I experimented with changing `config.cache_classes` and `config.action_controller.perform_caching` to false in both apps to no effect. (The one app on the domain root is serving static files if that matters)

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It doesn't tell a lot. Have you tried turning on asset pipeline debugging, and see what the output is? Here it tells you how to turn it off, but you just set it to true in order to enable it https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-debugging-off then check the `logs/development.log` to see what it spits out.

Comment: When I turn `config.assets.debug` to `true` in production it raises that it can't find any assets. It works fine in development.

Comment: Running `rails assets:clean` helped for a while linking between the two apps but now its doing it again. I also tried `rails assets:clobber` to no effect. Nginx is also reverse proxying to a static html pages in another subpath, and when I link from either of the apps to the static pages, it carries over styling from the compiled application.css there as well, which is fixed by a refresh. It seems like browsers are using cached css from other apps as long as they're in the same domain. Nginx is not caching itself.

Comment: I also tried setting `<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />` in both the applications and html pages with no effect. It does the same across multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by disabling turbolinks. Not sure if there’s a way to prevent turbolinks from causing this but this worked for me.